# Function to scale linear range that accentuates peaks

Tags: linear-algebra, scaling

I am monitoring an audio source and visualizing the power of each channel. I get a number out of the api (`averagePowerForChannel`, but the language/platform shouldn't be important for this problem).

When I add both numbers together I have a scale from `-240...0`. This makes sense as this is the decibel range.

I transform this scale to a linear representation of the same numbers from `0...1`. (I understand that decibels are logarithmic, I leave that alone and just map the scale linearly)

I then give the `0...1` value to an alpha channel that nicely represents the audio being played.

The problem is it's not showing enough change aesthetically. The value shifts slightly and usually hovers around 80:

```
alpha: 0.820713937282562
alpha: 0.816978693008423
alpha: 0.830410122871399
...
```

As you might imagine, this just creates a mild flicker.

Instead I'd like to accentuate the peaks of the audio. I have thrown some different methods at it:

```
//        var alpha = 1 / (1 + exp(1-linear)) // never gets fully bright, sits at about .45
//        var alpha = 1 - exp2(-linear) // stays around .45
//        var alpha = linear / linear + 1
```

These do not get me a good result, but then again I don't have any idea what I was trying to do.

#### Goal:

- low values on the range get pushed to zero or near zero (could even shift the range down `0.2` after the curve is calculated)
- Mid values are pushed lower
- High values have their differences accentuated (eg: .83 is shifted very close to 1, but .81 is shifted to .5)

I think I might want an exponential curve? I'm not sure. This is a very specific problem with known inputs so a magic number solution is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

I get a satisfactory visual by shifting the range to an interesting area, then using an exponential curve to emphasize changes from there on:

```
var alpha = volume / maxVolume
alpha = alpha - 0.5   // Shift the range over to the area with interesting differences in our source tracks
alpha = pow(alpha, 3) // Emphases the changes in this range
alpha *= 10           // Fix the decimal place
```

Will accept a better/more pure answer--for this I just wiggled numbers until they got me a good visual result. I'm sorry for grossing out the CS folks here :)

The best answer may be frequency isolation, but there is enough interesting difference to make a good visual without it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't invert the logarthmic scale:

> decibels = 10 * log10( value );

the inverse is just algebra:

> value = pow(10.0, decibels/10);

Observe that since your `decibels` are between -240 and 0, the `value` is between 0 (exclusive) and 1 (inclusive). That *should* ensure your values are more sparsely distributed. However if it still isn't, then your audio configuration might not be detecting significant changes in average amplitude - a not-so-unlikely possibility. In that case you might have to look at decomposing the audio into particular frequencies and looking at the amplitude of each frequency.

Comment: `pow(10.0, alpha/10) - 1` gives me values like `alpha: 0.153921653267586
alpha: 0.191564634627424
alpha: 0.215201322935747`. I think it's like you say--the feed isn't that differentiated.

Comment: Sorry I think i made a mistake in the post, your value to use in that equation should be the value you got from `averagePowerForChannel`, _not_ your alpha value _nor_ your linear value. That is what you did right?

Comment: I fed values into `pow(10.0 decibels/10)`. The value from averagePowerForChannel is `[-240...0]`. That gives values like: `0.00018452454241924`. skip. If I use the positive range `[0...240]` I get very high exponents. Should I map this output into `[0...1]` space next but lop off the high numbers at some point (since the curve approaches infinity, right?)